# AJAX GET & POST Method not working in Laravel .Showing Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to create a Dynamic Dependent DropDown of Country, State, City & SUb-City With laravel.

It's showing this error...[Main view page console showing the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU20A.)

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#provinces').on('change',function (e) {
       console.log(e);

       // var cId = e.target.value;
       var countryID = $(this).val();

       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/json-regencies',
           data:'country_id='+countryID,
           success:function(html){
               console.log(html);
               $('#regencies').html(html);
               $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
           }
       });


       // $.get('/json-regencies?cId='+cId,function (data) {
       //     console.log(data);
       // });
   });
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Indonesia</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>Laravel 5.5 JQuery Ajax Example</h2>
        <form>
         @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Your Provinces</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="provinces" id="provinces">
                    <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Provinces ===</option>
                    @foreach ($provinces as $key => $value)
                        <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->countryName }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Your Regencies</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="regencies" id="regencies">
                    <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Regencies ===</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Your Districts</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="districts" id="districts">
                    <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Districts ===</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Your Villages</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="villages" id="villages">
                    <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Villages ===</option>
                </select>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

```html
public function provinces(){
        $provinces = Country::all();
        return view('user.dependent', compact('provinces'));
    }

    public function regencies($id){
//        $provinces_id = Input::get('province_id');
        $regencies = State::where('countryId', $id)->get();
//        return response()->json($regencies);
        return $regencies;
    }

    public function districts(){
        $regencies_id = Input::get('regencies_id');
        $districts = City::where('stateId', $regencies_id)->get();
        return response()->json($districts);
    }

    public function villages(){
        $districts_id = Input::get('districts_id');
        $villages = Subcity::where('cityId', $districts_id)->get();
        return response()->json($villages);
    }
```

Comment: The image you've posted is no longer available.